# SNAP Upgrade Problems

Tags: sentinel-snap

Installed Sentinel Snap from official site on a Windows 10 virtual machine. Snap version 6.0.

Checked that I have administrative privileges before install, and asked to install "As an Administrator" to ensure everything runs fine.

After installation, updated SNAP using Tools / Plug-Ins window and selected all available plugins as per next image:

[image]

Restarted SNAP and noticed a "update is in progress..." message.

[image]

Opened Tools / Plugins menu again, and noticed that the system was not updated. I can see the full available updates on the list available to update.

I had no errors during update process.

Also noticed that when I close SNAP (File / Exit), the SNAP application open again and enters a loop. I close SNAP, and it opens again and no updates are made.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem.
Could not be a final workaround but solved my issue.

I was installing the SMS-Box and PROBA-V Toolbox included on the SANP setup application. Since I will not use those components, I disabled them during SNAP setup wizard.